# Add row in pandas DF as numeric column index?

Tags: python, pandas, shapes

I have tried this a few ways and am stumped.  My last attempt generates an error that says: "ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned"

So I have a dataframe that can have up to about 1,000 columns in it based on data read in from an external file.  The columns are all going to have their own labels/names, i.e. "Name", "BirthYear", Hometown", etc. I want to add a row at the beginning of the dataframe that runs from 0 to (as many columns as there are), so if the data ends up having 232 columns, this new first row would have values of 0,1,2,3,4....229,230,231,232.

What I am doing is creating a one-row dataframe with as many columns/values as there are in the main ("mega") dataframe, and then concatenating them. It throws this shape error at me, but when I print the shape of each frame, they match up in terms of length. Not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

```
colList = list(range(0, len(mega.columns)))
indexRow = pd.DataFrame(colList).T
print(indexRow)
print(indexRow.shape)
print(mega.shape)
mega = pd.concat([indexRow, mega],axis=0)
```

Here is the result...

```
  0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     ...   1045  \
0     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9  ...   1045   

   1046  1047  1048  1049  1050  1051  1052  1053  1054  
0  1046  1047  1048  1049  1050  1051  1052  1053  1054  

[1 rows x 1055 columns]
(1, 1055)
(4, 1055)
ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned
```

Comment: If the frame has 232 columns the your range will be 0 to 231 not 232, therefore range(0, len(mega.columns)-1)

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston but I tried that before.  If I do that, then the shapes end up being (1, 1038) and (4, 1039) and it still throws the same error. That's why I threw in the .shape print statements, so I could see if they actually had the same number of columns regardless of the start/end number in the row.

Comment: There should be no reason to need to add such a row of column indices. Why do you want to do it? Is it for computation, or for when writing output file? This seriously feels like an XY problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it. Depending on your data, this could mix types (e.g. if one column was timestamps).  Also, this resets your index in mega.

```
mega = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3), columns=list('ABC'))

indexRow = pd.DataFrame({col: [n] for n, col in enumerate(mega)})
>>> pd.concat([indexRow, mega], ignore_index=True)
          A         B         C
0  0.000000  1.000000  2.000000
1  0.413145 -1.475655  0.529429
2  0.416250 -0.055519  1.611539
3  0.154045 -0.038109  1.020616
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexander, but I end up with differing numbers of columns.  I implemented this exactly, and get the following:    FileNumber  Format  FormatNumber  ScaleName_x  FileName_x  PIName  12  \
0           0       1             2          366         368       5   6   

   SubjectNumber_x  14  SiteNumber     ...       ADASCog_329  ADASCog_330  \
0              367   8           9     ...              1015         1016   

   ADASCog_336  ADASCog_337  ADASCog_338  
0         1022         1023         1024  

[1 rows x 1012 columns]
(1, 1012)
(4, 1025)

Comment: So one df has 2012 columns, whereas the main/mega df has 1025.  Still throws the same error.

Comment: You probably have duplicate column names. `mega.columns[mega.columns.duplicated()]`. If so, try: `indexRow = pd.DataFrame(list(range(df.shape[1])), index=mega.columns).T`